# What is the best way to save values (like strings) for later use?

Tags: content-replication, alias

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and I'm struggling with something apparently simple, but for which I can't find a fair solution.
The problem (simplified) is as follows (please take care terms used may not have the traditional meaning in LaTeX):

I need to references to files (*many*) throughout a text. As example, the files: 
`"C:/Work/this_file1.c"`, `"C:/MoreWork/this_file1.c"` and `"D:/MoreWork/another_file2.h"`.

So, now I would like to create an "alias" to each directory and each name file so I can reference them. A "pseudocode" could be:

```
% Definition
\alias \c_dir = C:/Work/
\alias \d_dir = D:/MoreWork/
\alias \file1 = this_file1.c
\alias \file2 = another_file2.h

% Reference in text
\c_dir\file1    % For referencing C:/Work/this_file1.c
\d_dir\file1    % For referencing D:/MoreWork/this_file1.c
\c_dir\file2    % For referencing C:/Work/another_file2.h
```

My first approach was using `\newcommand`, but that caused numerous problems due to naming limitations. (I also tried other methods like `pgfkeys`, but it always gets stuck somewhere!)

Can you suggest a method?

Comment: just use `\newcommand` while just using letters for the name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Dont forget to mark a solution. Very good first question by the way. Very easy to understand, clear expectation.

Answer (score 18):

For more flexible alias names, you can do it like this. In the examples I removed the underscore; depending on the intended usage you may want to escape them (`\_`) or not (`_`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\alias[2]{\expandafter\def\csname alias:#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\A[1]{\csname alias:#1\endcsname}

\alias{c_dir}{C:/Work/}
\alias{d_dir}{D:/MoreWork/}
\alias{file1}{thisFile1.c}
\alias{file2}{anotherFile2.h}

\begin{document}
\A{c_dir}\A{file1}

\A{d_dir}\A{file1}

\A{c_dir}\A{file2}
\end{document}
```

---

As suggested by @MaestroGlanz, the commands `\alias` and `\A` can be defined more compactly using the package `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\alias[2]{\csdef{alias:#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\A[1]{\csuse{alias:#1}}
```

---

Because mentioned in the original question, here a `pgfkeys` solution (though I'm not aware of any advantage):

```
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newcommand\alias[2]{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/alias/#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\A[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/alias/#1}}
```

---

The result of the sample document in all versions:

[image]

Comment: You should add a version with `\csdef` from the etoolbox. This is more understandable for a rookie.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Thanks for the suggestion, added.

Answer (score 14):

You can just use `\newcommand`, so long as the command names obey tex rules (consist of letters, essentially).

```
% Definition
\newcommand\cdir{C:/Work/}
\newcommand\ddir{D:/MoreWork/}
\newcommand\fileA{this\_file1.c}
\newcommand\fileB{another\_file2.h}

% Reference in text
\cdir\fileA    % For referencing C:/Work/this_file1.c
\ddir\fileA    % For referencing D:/MoreWork/this_file1.c
\cdir\fileB    % For referencing C:/Work/another_file2.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your replies... that were quite useful... and made me go a little further.

First, the initial question is not as clear as should be, so a more 'real' example should do the trick:

In the LaTeX document I need to "include" parts of external files (typically software source code). The source files need to be copied to a temporary location and (Important) get a temporary name (something like `temp1.tmp`, `temp2.tmp`... and so on). [Note: how the copy is made is of no concern... just that the paths and filenames must be tracked.]

So, below I have the solution that I'm using. Just sharing...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{cntTmp}
\newcommand{\mylongS}[4]{
    % In here I pass the source and destination file parameters
    srcDir: #1; srcFile: #2; dstDir: #3; dstFile: #4    

    %I Now use the parameters to create a string to store in a just-defined key
    \define@key{}{this\arabic{cntTmp}}[]{#1:#2:#3:#4}
    \stepcounter{cntTmp}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    % This should "account" as the first file copied... to temp0.tmp    
    \mylongS{S:/work}{testtxt}{t}{temp0.tmp}

    % This should "account" as the SECOND file copied... to temp1.tmp   
    \mylongS{S:/work}{testtxt}{t}{temp1.tmp}

    % Now I have access to the full string... and may use string manipulation
    \setkeys{}{this0}

    \setkeys{}{this1}
\end{document}
```